# Asymptotic solving of a hyperbolic equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

The solition and anti-solition nonlinear equation is given as:[image]

My problem is that, how do we get the next equation after considering asyptotic behaviour?

Resource: ([solition](http://users.ugent.be/~ddudal/sol&mon.pdf)) at page 38

Comment: What is $\Delta$?  Is $u$ related to $\bar{t}$ in any way?

Comment: Can you please check this book (http://users.ugent.be/~ddudal/sol&mon.pdf) at page 38?

Comment: I'm confused why you ask what $\Delta$ is.  You yourself linked me to the pdf which says $$\Delta = ((1-u^2)/u)\ln u.$$

Comment: Ohh my bad, then we just need to transform the hyperbolic term into  exponential?

Comment: It seems plausible, but I haven't carried out the calculations.

Comment: can you do a little please?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that:
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sinh(x) \sim -e^{-x}$$
And that: $$\cosh x =\frac{1}{2}e^{-x} + \frac{1}{2}e^x$$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $e^{-x}/2$?

Comment: What will happen when you impose the $- \infty$?