# Nonlinear solution condition and graphical representation

Tags: graphing-functions, mathematical-physics, nonlinear-system

The solution of a nonlinear solitary wave equation can be written as 
$$\phi(x)  = \pm v \tanh\left[\frac{m}{ \sqrt 2} (x-x_0)\right]$$
where the plus and minus refer to the kink and antikink solutions respectively and $x_0$ is a constant of integration.

I don't understand the following claim

> The energy density is localized near $x = x_0$ and goes to zero exponentially fast for $|x- x_0 | > 1/m$.

Can anyone explain this to me with a mathematical argument and graphical picture?

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The illustration  looks like:
[image]

Can we do it by Mathematica? 
Source: R. Rajamaran, Solitons and Instantons (North-Holland,Amsterdam, 1987) page no 21.

Comment: Hint: The energy density for $\phi^4$ theory is given by:
$$\frac12 |\nabla \phi(x)|^2 + \frac{m^2}{4v^2} (\phi(x)^2 - v^2)^2$$
What do you get if you plug your kink/anti-kink solution to it?

Comment: The Lagrangian density is defined for this solution is \begin{align*}
V(\phi)= \frac{1}{4}\lambda \left(\phi^2-\frac{m^2}{\lambda}\right)^2
\end{align*}

Comment: @ComplexGuy: you have written down the potential term for the system. The Lagrangian density is defined to be the difference between the kinetic term $\frac{1}{2}|\nabla \phi|^2$ and your potential term $V(\phi)$. The energy density is defined to be the sum of these terms. This is exactly what achille hui wrote down (if you scale your constants to match his).

Comment: @EdwardHughes that mistake comes from Rajamaran's book (I've a copy in front of me).

Comment: yup got it. Now if I put the solution then I get the hyperbolic tanh in the Lagrangian energy. But how to proximate to the graph and the explanation for the exponential  explanation?

Comment: @achille hui,  you are right.

Comment: Have you written out $tanh$ in terms of exponentials? I haven't actually done the calculation, but it sounds like this would help...

Comment: Will I use this formula ?  $\tanh x = \frac{1 - e^{-2x}} {1 + e^{-2x}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy functional for $\phi^4$ theory is given by:

$$E(\phi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varepsilon(\phi,x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\frac12 |\nabla \phi(x)|^2 + \frac{m^2}{4v^2} (\phi(x)^2 - v^2)^2 \right] dx$$

If one substitute the kink or anti-kink solution to the energy density $\varepsilon(\phi,x)$, one
get
$$\varepsilon(\phi,x) = \frac{m^2v^2}{2 \cosh(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}(x-x_0))^4}$$

Since $\cosh(x) \sim \frac12 e^{|x|}$ for large $x$, we find
$$\varepsilon(\phi,x) \sim 8m^2v^2 e^{-2\sqrt{2}m |x-x_0|}\quad\text{ as }\quad x \to \pm \infty$$

To understand the exponential behavior for large $x$, let us look at the 
equation of motion of $\phi$ derived from varying the energy functional:

$$\frac{\delta E(\phi)}{\delta \phi} = 0 
\quad\implies\quad
-\frac{d^2\phi(x)}{dx^2} + \frac{m^2}{v^2}\phi(x)(\phi(x)^2 - v^2) = 0\tag{*}
$$

For concreteness, let us look as the case where $\phi(x)$ is the kink solution 
and $x$ is large and positive. We know $\phi(x) \to v$ as $x \to +\infty$.
This suggest us rewrite $\phi(x)$ as $v + \eta(x)$ and expand $(*)$ in powers 
of  $\eta(x)$, we obtain:
$$-\frac{d^2\eta(x)}{dx^2} + 2 m^2 \eta(x) + O(\eta(x)^2) = 0$$

This implies for large positive $x$, $\eta(x)$ falls off exponentially as $e^{-\sqrt{2}m x}$. If we do the same thing to the energy density, we find:

$$\varepsilon(\phi,x) \sim \frac12 |\nabla \eta(x)|^2 + m^2 \eta(x)^2 + O(\eta(x)^3)$$

Since the leading dependence of $\eta(x)$ in the energy density is quadratic, $\varepsilon(\phi,x)$ falls off twice as fast as $\phi(x)$, i.e. exponentially as $e^{-2\sqrt{2}m x}$. The is what we have obtained before by an explicit computation of $\varepsilon(\phi,x)$.

Comment: $\varepsilon(\phi,x) \sim 8m^2v^2 e^{-2\sqrt{2}m |x-x_0|}\quad\text{ as }\quad x \to \pm \infty$ 

this terms arises asymptotically? can you please simplify  this a bit more?

 **Sorry too many questions!!!**
Are we guessing the variation is zero due to infinitesimal  variance? $\frac{\delta E(\phi)}{\delta \phi} = 0 
\quad\
$

I'm confused with this term, can you elaborate  please?  $-\frac{d^2\eta(x)}{dx^2} + 2 m^2 \eta(x) + O(\eta(x)^2) = 0$ and how this term

Comment: The kink/anti-kink solutions are the minimum of the energy functional subject to the given boundary condition. That's why the kink/anti-link solution is physically stable. Being a minimum, its variation need to be $0$ and that's how you get the equation of motion. For the expression of $\varepsilon(\phi,x)$ and the ODE in $\eta(x)$, you will get them if you sit down and do the algebra. The derivation is pretty short and no tricks involved.

Comment: Is there any way to visualize by Mathematica?  I mean the exponential characteristics visualizations.

Comment: @ComplexGuy Sorry, I don't have access to Mathematica. It is way too expensive once you get out of academia.

Comment: Okay thanks.
If you have time then please have a look at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467128/asymptotic-solving/475671?noredirect=1#475671 .